# Which is the best Stack Exchange site to ask questions concerning Asterisk, a VoIP phone system?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

[Asterisk](https://www.asterisk.org/) is a server-based [VoIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_over_IP) phone system that is usually run on Linux, and usually run on a network. I have seen posts for Asterisk on Server Fault, Stack Overflow, and Super User. I even saw one post somewhere in those sites (sorry, I can't remember where and cannot find it in my history) where there was a debate about whether the user's Asterisk question ought to be posted in Super User or Server Fault.

[What is Asterisk](https://serverfault.com/questions/219390/what-is-asterisk) (now deleted) is an Asterisk question migrated from Super User to Server Fault.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800924/asterisk-unable-to-connect-to-remote-asterisk-does-var-run-asterisk-ctl-exis) (now deleted) is a comment on Stack Overflow, by a rep of 635 where the user was told his/her question would be better asked on Super User or Server Fault.

Hence, what is the most relevant Q&A site for this, Server Fault, Stack Overflow, or Super User?

Comment: How would [Network Engineering.SE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) fit in to this with its `telephony` and `voip` tags, now that the Telephony beta mentioned in @Marcos answer seems to have disappeared?

Comment: Evidently they don’t want [telephone server questions](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/83776/how-to-reroute-a-dial-pattern-to-another-phone-number). Their mod says “questions about hosts/servers, applications, and protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here”.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Is your question about the use or configuration of Asterisk as a PBX for your **office**? If so, Server Fault.

Is your question about writing a client or module for Asterisk, or working on the codebase of Asterisk itself? If so, Stack Overflow.

Is your question about the use or configuration of Asterisk as a **home** PBX, or the use of clients connecting to Asterisk? If so, Super User.

Answer (score 5):

I would say Server Fault, because it’s a server technology.  Questions about developing for Asterisk *might* be on-topic for Stack Overflow if code is involved.

Comment: But so often the questions that need answering with Asterisk involve code because it is configured through .conf text files - which is code.  If you say questions involving code _might_ go to StackOverflow, how would you differentiate?

Comment: @BGM Config files are not code.

Comment: Would you consider them code if they contain macros?  I can assure you that extensions.conf contains macros.

Comment: @BGM That could be considered code, but its a grey area.

Comment: @BGM when I said questions involving code might go to [so], I meant writing custom extensions, plugin, etc.  Questions regarding pure configuration are most assuredly off topic for [so]

Comment: It's painful when you write a perfectly good question in the place you think it ought to be and it gets closed - or worse, migrated, then closed on the other site.

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be a Telephony/Telecommunications SE in beta now.

Two of Zypher's choices https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131756/184368 seem to apply equally well with the Google search that landed me here ("How to reset Asterisk's admin GUI password using CLI / config files").

Comment: I wish the beta site luck. It was tried once before and failed, and its topics rolled into [sf], where they remain welcome.

Comment: Did the telephony site fail again? It seems to have vanished.

Comment: @DannyBeckett it was merged into [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/).